# Printing numbers in loop with two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying out codes with multiple threads.
Below is my code:

```
package com.thread.practice;

public class ThreadPratice1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r, "Thread 1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r, "Thread 2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

package com.thread.practice;

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private static int i = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(i = 0; i <10;i++){
            System.out.println("Thread: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    +" value of i: "+i);
            try {
                //System.out.println("Thread: "+ i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                //System.out.println("inside runnable: "+Thread.currentThread().getState());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in the output it is always printing the value of i as 0 twice in the beginning.

Output is coming kind of like this:

```
Thread: Thread 1 value of i: 0
Thread: Thread 2 value of i: 0
Thread: Thread 1 value of i: 2
Thread: Thread 2 value of i: 2
Thread: Thread 1 value of i: 3
Thread: Thread 2 value of i: 4
Thread: Thread 1 value of i: 5
Thread: Thread 2 value of i: 6
Thread: Thread 1 value of i: 7
Thread: Thread 2 value of i: 8
Thread: Thread 1 value of i: 9
```

May someone please help me in understanding this issue?

Comment: every thread you start initialises `i` back to `0` in the `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

Because the value of `i` at the begging of the execution of the two threads is `0`.

In other words, thread one and thread two stared almost at the same time, so the two of them set the `i` to 0 for the first loop.

```
for(i = 0; i <10;i++) {
```

Then the value changes between thread because you made `i` static. so it will be shared between your two threads.

Comment: Ok. But when the first thread get executed shouldn't it increase the value to 1. Thus when the second thread gets chance shouldn't it print 1 ?

Comment: No, it will not increase the value to 1 at the first enter, since you re-initializing the `i` again by saying `for(i = 0; i <10;i++) {`

Answer (score 2):

You made "i" static, which means it will be the same over all threads and objects. Take away the static modifier and your code will work properly.

edit: I misinterpreted what you asked- don't set i to 0 in the for loop, it will look something like this:

```
for(;i<10;i++) { /*mycode*/}
```

One of these two is probably what you want anyway, your question was a little bit vague

Answer (score 0):

value of `i` is incremented by the for loop only after the loop is executed. Execution of for loop takes a finite amount of time. Since you are starting the threads together (almost), both the threads may or may not print `i` after the other thread has finished one loop. Since you are not doing to ensure thread safety, the result will be unpredictable like the one you got.

Answer (score 0):

First, You shouldn't use the primitive **int** type for concurrency, it's not thread safe and it maybe will cause [Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition),

and try to use `AtomicInteger` to replace `int`, it's thread safe. the example maybe:

```
public class ThreadPratice1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicInteger number = new AtomicInteger(0);
        MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable(number);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r, "Thread 1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r, "Thread 2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private AtomicInteger number;

    public MyRunnable(AtomicInteger number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (number.get() < 10) {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + " value of i: " + number.getAndIncrement());
        }
    }
}
```